# How to change the style properties of uib-accordion-heading

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

The solution for the problem is already there/I have. But if I change the resource file version(inside head tag) from **ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js** to **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js**, it is not working proper....Since I have done 90% work in **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js**, it is not possible to include **ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js** for me(if I change these, other functions are not working).

1.[Plunker demo which contains **ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js**](https://plnkr.co/edit/psdfd9gKdKxKUWvl5wRx?p=preview)

2.[Plunker demo which contains **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js**](http://plnkr.co/edit/P4ZjNYX6lQFz4nSZMJXY?p=preview)

Totally, I need to change the color/background-color of _*uib-accordion-heading*__ using **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js**, Can anyone help me pls....

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:blue;">
            <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:red;">
                <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
                    <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
                        {{heading}}
                    </span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
            <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
            This content is straight in the template.
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Dynamic Body Content">
            <p>The body of the uib-accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
            <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-info" heading="Custom template" template-url="group-template.html">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.isCustomHeaderOpen" template-url="group-template.html">
            <uib-accordion-heading>
                Custom template with custom header template <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.isCustomHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.isCustomHeaderOpen}"></i>
            </uib-accordion-heading>
            World
        </div>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use a CSS rule, like `span[uib-accordion-header] { ... }`

Comment: Yes..it works, thanks a lot....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
                <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
                    {{heading}}
                </span>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</script>
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
        This content is straight in the template.
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{group.content}}
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Dynamic Body Content">
        <p>The body of the uib-accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-info" heading="Custom template" template-url="group-template.html">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.isCustomHeaderOpen" template-url="group-template.html">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            Custom template with custom header template <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.isCustomHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.isCustomHeaderOpen}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        World
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

**CSS**

`.panel-info .panel-heading {
  background: blue;
  color: red;
}`

If you want to apply the custom-style for default then use the below css

`.panel-default .panel-heading {
/* Css Properties */
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the style generated by javascript file with this css rule to solve the problem.

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  color: #f00 !important;
  background-color: #00f !important;
}
```

Comment: If possible, try not to use `!important`

Comment: yeah..thanks for the suggestion. But if you want to override the style generated by JS then only you can use !important.